# WSO2 GREG Service created from wsdl is locked

Tags: registry, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

When import the wsdl into GREG, automatically GREG create the service artifact, but this artifact is locked is uneditable. Some workaround ?

Comment: Could you specify which G-reg version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifact is locked becuase, the service artifact is supposed to reflect the state of the WSDL.

However, the locking happens using the permission model. So if you really want to edit the info for the service artifact generated against the WSDL, you can change the permissions for service artifacts from read-only to read-write and then edit the service data the way you want.